# Engine coolant below minimum after driving

Tags: engine, coolant

I filled engine coolant to max.  After driving it went below the minimum. Is this ok, or is there something wrong?

Comment: Maybe. Where did you add coolant? What kind of vehicle did you add it to?

Comment: Welcome to mechanics.stackexchange!  I've edited your post to improve clarity.  Feel welcome to change my edits if I haven't expressed your intents correctly.

Comment: Was this a one time occurrence? Or have you done this several times with the same results?

Comment: How long did you drive for?

Answer (score 1):

If you checked it immediately after driving the car it just hasn't settled back into the reservoir. Check it again after the car completely cools off.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal, check your radiator and hoses for leaks. If there are no leaks, check if the radiator cap seals correctly, if the rubber seal is damaged the coolant can evaporate.